# Adding/Removing Checkbox Values into TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I scoured the the site and found a few examples, I got close but not close enough.
I have 2 checkboxes and if a user checks them they are placed in the textarea, if the user removes the check. the value is removed. I want to keep cursor position too.

I am able  to add but its still clunky.

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/pU2P9/18/

here is my code

Testing. Values from another field will be inserted here.

```
    <form>

           <p>Favorite Color  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Green" />Green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Red" />Red</label></p>
    </form>


 var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextArea1");
  // $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
  var $parentForm = $(this).closest("form");

 // var text = $(".insert-text", $parentForm).val();
  var text = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val() + " ";

 //  var text = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked', $parentForm).val() + " ";

  insertAtCursor(textarea, text);
  });

 function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
  if (document.selection) {
    myField.focus();
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = myValue;
}

else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
    var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
    var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
    myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue +            myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
  }
else {
    myField.value += myValue;
    }
 }
 ;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure **exactly** what you are trying to do, but it seems you're a little confused.

Try something like

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var text = $(this).val() + " ";
        insertAtCursor(textarea, text);    
    }
});
```

Comment: very close. i just need the checkbox to delete if it unchecked and were good.  I can keep clicking the checkbox and it keeps adding , i need to to remove trying to think of the logic

Comment: your solution while it didnt delete, the cursor kept position and added the checkbox value perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to drive yourself crazy trying to treat the `textarea` like you are.  You can prepend the colors easily enough, but what do you do when the user un-checks them?  For example, what if they check green, then red, then un-checks green?  It's now no longer a simple matter of removing 5 characters from the `textarea`.

If I understand your application, though, you're combining values from different fields in the `textarea`, so I would do something like this:

```
function updateTextArea() {
  var text = "";
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each( function() {
    text += $(this).val() + " ";
  });
  $('input[type=text]').each( function() {
    text += $(this).val() + " ";
  });
  $('#myTextArea1').val( text );
}
```

Then you can just call this every time one of your values changes.  For example, when the user changes one of the check boxes:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
  updateTextArea();
});
```

I believe that this will be much cleaner than the approach you're outlining.  You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/8y4D8/19/

Also, you could consider using Backbone.js (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) or some similar Javascript MVC framework.

Comment: im just using this for a twitter textbox, they will check the box to add a particular hashtag where ever in there status message. I used colors to show the example easier. let me see if i can get the cursor part working now and i am good